# React no renderiza los cambios con el setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vistas

tengo que hacer esta actividad
Para este primer reto de programación en React vamos a poner en practica lo aprendido hasta ahora para crear dos componentes.

Cada uno de estos componentes tendrá sus propias características.

Componente A: Este componente va a tener disponer un Contacto(crea una clase para ello), que va a contar con las siguientes características:

Nombre: que será un String.

Apellido: también un String.

Email: de nuevo un String.

Conectado: será un booleano que nos indicará si la persona está conectada o no.

Componente B: Por otro lado, tenemos el componente B que va a recibir por props un contacto y va a poder cambiar su estado de conectado a desconectado y viceversa.

Si el contacto está conectado, se debe mostrar: Contacto En Línea

Si el contacto no está conectado, se debe mostrar: Contacto No Disponible

Renderizado de componentes en la solución:

El Componente A debe ser renderizado dentro del componente App.js del proyecto.

El Componente B debe ser renderizado desde el componte A y recibir los props adecuadamente

Recordatorio: Haz uso de Proptypes adecuadamente

La cuestión es que el programa renderiza bien las vistas el problema esta en cuando quiero cambiar el estado del conectar que es un booleano, este se cambia pero renderiza el resultado en la vista, vale aclarar que en la herramienta React Developer Tools en la parte de components se muestran los cambios del booleano pero no en las vistas, si alguien me puede dar una mano con esto se lo agradecería.

```
import React from 'react';

const ContactoF = ({ contacto }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>nombre: {contacto.nombre}</h1>
      <h2>apellido: {contacto.apellido}</h2>
      <h3>email: {contacto.email}</h3>
      <h4>
        conectado:{' '}
        {contacto.state.conectado
          ? 'Contacto En Línea'
          : 'Contacto No Disponible'}
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactoF;
```

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import ContactoF from './contactoF';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

class Contacto extends Component {
  nombre;
  apellido;
  email;

  constructor(nombre, apellido, email) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.email = email;
    this.state = {
      conectado: true,
      cont: 0,
    };
    this.conectar = this.conectar.bind(this);
    this.desconectar = this.desconectar.bind(this);
  }

  conectar = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return { conectado: (state.conectado = true) };
    });
  };

  desconectar = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return { conectado: (state.conectado = false) };
    });
  };
  render() {
    const contact = new Contacto('Leo', 'pepe', 'pepe@hotmail.com');
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.conectar}>Conectar</button>
        <button onClick={this.desconectar}>Desconectar</button>
        <ContactoF
          contacto={contact}
          conectar={this.conectar}
          desconectar={this.desconectar}
        ></ContactoF>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Contacto.propTypes = {
  contacto: PropTypes.instanceOf(Contacto),
};

export default Contacto;
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro, estoy recien empezando con react y viendolo de open boot camp es mas o menos asi como lo hacen pero supongo que son cosas permisivas al ser el inicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que no les estás pasando el `conectado` como props a `ContactoF`.

Estás intentando esto.

```
<h4>
    conectado: { contacto.state.conectado ? "Contacto En Línea" : "Contacto No Disponible"}
</h4>
```

Pero en las proas le estás pasando esto.

```
<ContactoF
    contacto={contact}
    conectar={this.conectar}
    desconectar={this.desconectar}
></ContactoF>
```

y `contact` es `const contact = new Contacto("Leo", "pepe", "pepe@hotmail.com");` por lo que el `state` de ese elemento no es el mismo del `state` que estás cambiando, es decir tienes un **objeto *A* del tipo *Contacto*** Ahí estás mandando a llamar un **Objeto *B* del tipo *ContactoF*** al cuál le estás pasando como propiedad un **Objeto *C* del tipo *Contacto***. Observa que a pesar de ser del mismo tipo, el **Objeto A** y el **Objeto C** No son los mismos, por lo que al hacer clic en el botón, estás cambiando el `state` del **objeto A** no del **Objeto C** que es el que pasas.

Para solucionarlo, simplemente. pasa ese `boolean` a través de los pros y luego úsalo en el `ContactoF`

```
<ContactoF contacto={contact} conectado={this.state.conectado}/>
```

Y luego en tu clase `contactoF`

```
const ContactoF = ({contacto, conectado}) => {

    return (
        <div>
           ... //El resto de tu código
            <h4>
                conectado: {conectado ? "Contacto En Línea" : "Contacto No Disponible"}
            </h4>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**NOTA**

No es muy conveniente crear una clase que estás usando como componente para pasarla a través de los pros y obtener los datos, para eso sirve el `state`, o mejor aún ya que no cambia y puedes pasarla como `props` a través de los componentes, esto te da un mejor uso de `reusabilidad` que es al final de lo que trata `react`

Así quedaría lo mismo pero un mejor uso de los `state` y los `props`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const ContactoF = ({nombre, apellido, email, conectado}) => (
  <div>
    <h1> nombre: { nombre } </h1>
    <h2> apellido: { apellido } </h2>
    <h3> email: { email } </h3>
    <h4> conectado: { conectado ? "Contacto En Línea" : "Contacto No Disponible"} </h4>
  </div>
);

class Contacto extends Component {

  constructor({nombre, apellido, email}) {
    super();
    this.state = { conectado: true };
    this.conectar = this.conectar.bind(this);
    this.desconectar = this.desconectar.bind(this);
  }

  conectar = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {...state, conectado: true}
    });
  }

  desconectar = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {...state, conectado: false}
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.conectar}>Conectar</button>
        <button onClick={this.desconectar}>Desconectar</button>
        <ContactoF
          {...this.props}
          conectado= {this.state.conectado}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Contacto
      nombre="Pedro"
      apellido="Perez"
      email="pedro@perez.com"
    />
  );
}
```

Ya de aquí tú solo tendrías que separarlo en archivos y ponerle los `PropTypes`

Comment: muchas gracias bro por la ayuda y la explicacion

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un enfoque algo confuso en cuanto a la creación de componentes y de instanciación de clases.

Yo lo dividi de la siguiente manera:

- Clase Contacto para crear nuevos contactos.

```
class Contacto {
  nombre;
  apellido;
  email;

  constructor(nombre, apellido, email) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.email = email;
  }
}

export default Contacto;
```

- Component de Contacto en el cual almacenas el estado de dicho
  contacto y controlas los eventos como conectar o desconectar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ContactoF from './contactoF';
import Contact from './Contact';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

class ContactoComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      conectado: true,
      cont: 0,
    };
    this.conectar = this.conectar.bind(this);
    this.desconectar = this.desconectar.bind(this);
  }

  conectar = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return { conectado: (state.conectado = true) };
    });
  };

  desconectar = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({ ...this.state, conectado: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { contact } = this.props;
    const { conectado } = this.state;
    console.log(contact);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.conectar}>Conectar</button>
        <button onClick={this.desconectar}>Desconectar</button>
        <ContactoF contacto={contact} conectado={conectado}></ContactoF>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ContactoComponent.propTypes = {
  contacto: PropTypes.instanceOf(Contact),
};

export default ContactoComponent;
```

- Componente que muestra la información del contacto

```
import React from 'react';

const ContactoF = ({ contacto, conectado }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>nombre: {contacto.nombre}</h1>
      <h2>apellido: {contacto.apellido}</h2>
      <h3>email: {contacto.email}</h3>
      <h4>
        conectado: {conectado ? 'Contacto En Línea' : 'Contacto No Disponible'}
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactoF;
```

- Y por ultimo un pequeno ejemplo utilizando los componentes arriba
  mencionados

```
import React from 'react';
import ContactoComponent from './ContactoComponent';
import Contact from './Contact';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const contact = new Contact('Alex', 'Perez', 'aperez@gmail.com');
  const contact1 = new Contact('Ramon', 'Aguilar', 'raguilar@gmail.com');
  const contact2 = new Contact('Rosa', 'Meltros...', 'rosa@meltro.so');

  return (
    <div>
      <ContactoComponent contact={contact} />
      <ContactoComponent contact={contact1} />
      <ContactoComponent contact={contact2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Aca una pequeña muestra de como funciona:

https://react-mj4wec.stackblitz.io/

Espero sea de tu ayuda, Saludos!

Comment: No tiene sentido manejar `clases` para generar un `objeto` cuando realmente incluso haciendo `{nombre: 'Alex', apellido: 'Perez'...}` crea un `objeto` como tal. Además de limitar el poder cambiar dichas variables a través de algún `state`. Cuál sería la ventaja de ello o para qué hacerlo?

Comment: Es valido tu comentario en referencia la necesidad de crear una clase para crear dichos objetos y en efecto lo puede hacer como indicas; pero la respuesta fue dada en base al enfoque que posee su código (crear clases e instancias de objtos) no a lo que yo quiero que el haga.

Comment: Si te tomaste la molestia de separar el código, no veo porque no dar el valor agregado y explicar el porqué no es bueno hacerlo como le hace, al final es parte de una respuesta completa, pues no solo ayuda a solucionar su problema, sino a que entienda el porqué de las cosas.